# Passing constants to a function parameter that is an open array of record

Tags: delphi, record, open-array-parameters

I have a record defined like this:

```
TRec = record
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
end;
```

I can initialize a constant of this record type like this:

```
const
  Rec: TRec = (S:'Test'; I:123);
```

Now I have a function that takes an open array of this record type:

```
function Test(AParams: array of TRec);
```

Can I call this function using similar syntax as the constant declaration?

```
Test([(S:'S1'; I:1), (S:'S2'; I:2)]);
```

This does not work.  Should I use something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a constructor to the record type, which takes the parameters needed.

```
TRec = record
  s : string;
  i : integer;
  constructor create( s_ : string; i_: integer );
end;

constructor TRec.create( s_ : string; i_: integer );
begin
  s := s_;
  i := i_;
end;

procedure test( recs_ : array of TRec );
var
  i : Integer;
  rec : TRec;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(recs_) do
    rec := recs_[i];
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click( sender_ : TObject );
begin
  test( [TRec.create('1',1), TRec.create('2',2)] );
end;
```

As Remy Lebeau reflected, it works just with  Delphi 2006 or newer versions. If you have an older IDE you should create an utility class with a method (along with other methods) witch conforms to the record constructor above:

```
TRecUtility = class
  public
    class function createRecord( s_ : string; i_: integer ) : TRec;
    //... other utility methods
end;

procedure foo;
begin
  test( [TRecUtility.createRec('1',1), TRec.createRec('2',2)] ); 
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this is known decision, thanks. I was hoping this could be easier

Comment: @RemyLebeau Previous versions need a utility class with a method conforms to this constructor.